# Solr search in rails across multiple models not redirecting to search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

I'm looking around and I can't find my solution.

I'm creating a search across multiple models in my rails app. Right now, I have it set up with two models, a user and a community. My search works fine when I go to '/search' and then perform the search in the nav bar.

My issue is that when a user tries to search for something in the main search bar in the nav, it's not redirecting or forwarding to '/search'. It just forwards to the following link:

http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&commit=Search

However, I really need it to go to:

http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&commit=Search

in order for the search to redirected and completed.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/search', to: 'search#search'
```

**search controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @search = Sunspot.search Community,User do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @results = @search.results
  end
end
```

**community.rb**

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :description, :expanded_description
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :username
    text :name
  end
end
```

**header view (in haml)**

```
%form.navbar-form.navbar-left
  = form_tag search_path, method: 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control'
    = submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Many thanks ahead of time or if there is another question similar, please point me to the way.

Below are my logs to what happens when I search.

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=new&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2016-04-12 17:01:52 -0400
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"new", "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Membership Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `memberships`.* FROM `memberships` WHERE `memberships`.`user_id` = 1
  Rendered home/_communities_blank_state.html.haml (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer_ctas.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered home/_dashboard.html.haml (4.5ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (8.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_alerts.html.haml (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (1.6ms)
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users' }

  devise_scope :users do
    resources :profiles, controller: "profile"
  end

  root to: 'home#index'

  get 'portal', to: 'home#portal'

  get '/search', to: 'search#search', as: :search

  resources :communities do
    resources :supplements
  end

  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  get '/contact_us' => 'contacts#new'

  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out my issue and unfortunately I didn't realize a class tag would mess with my search but it did. I had the form_tag inside of a "form" class, by having a form within a form, it gave me the issues.

I updated my views with below and it worked.

```
.navbar-form.navbar-left
  = form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:query], class: 'form-control'
    = submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Comment: Wow! I'm glad you made it work! It did bug me when we tried to resolve this, but I thought it's irrelevant. It's usually done like this: `= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get', :html => { :class => '[your classes]' } do`, but at the time I just didn't think that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to name your route if you want to use `form_tag search_path`.

You need to do the following in your `routes.rb`:

```
get '/search', to: 'search#search', as: :search
```

This way it should work.

Comment: What does your `index` route look like? In your log, it says that the request is being processed by `HomeController#index`, not `SearchController#search`

Comment: if I understand correctly, are you asking where my root is? like   ``root to: 'home#index' ``

Comment: I dont have an index route for my search

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Weird, I've tested the same search form with precisely your routes, and it works perfectly. Something else must be wrong on your side. Could you please provide your full `routes.rb`?

Comment: Oh gosh... that's so weird. Updated are my routes. What's weird, is that the search param is being passed in the back of the url instead of the beginning, which would redirect me to the results.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your routes, but could you put the `search` route above `root` route? See if that helps. Actually, it would be even better if you provided an output of `rake routes` command (Or, if you're using Rails 5, `rails routes`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109069/discussion-between-alexander-komarov-and-agirlthatcodes).